SAML authentication handler contains unsafe inline script - Unable to redirect to Okta login page
We are using a nonce worker to avoid loading inline scripts,
But SAML authentication handler contains a form that redirects to the OKTA login page.
This form includes an unsafe inline script, which prevents the page from rendering and redirects to the OKTA login page.
Any one have faced this issue?


not the way you are doing but just a link button can forward to Okta and SAML auth handler handling it.
